# conditionally mutate new column depending on date and predefined value - data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Data:

```
DT<-data.table::data.table(
          ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
       C_OPR = c("ABCD01", "ABCD11", NA, "EFGH", NA, NA, "KLMN", NA),
       D_OPR = c(NA, NA, "PQRST", NA, "EFGHIJ", NA, NA, NA),
        DATE = c("2007-07-07","2005-05-05","2002-02-02",
                 "2002-02-02","2004-04-04",NA,"2001-01-01",NA),
   INDX_DATE = c("2006-06-06","2006-06-06","2006-06-06",
                 "2001-01-01","2001-01-01","2001-01-01","2005-05-05",
                 "2005-05-05")
)

ALFA_DEF<-c("ABCD","EFGH")
```

Output:

```
   ID  C_OPR  D_OPR       DATE  INDX_DATE
1:  1 ABCD01   <NA> 2007-07-07 2006-06-06
2:  1 ABCD11   <NA> 2005-05-05 2006-06-06
3:  1   <NA>  PQRST 2002-02-02 2006-06-06
4:  2   EFGH   <NA> 2002-02-02 2001-01-01
5:  2   <NA> EFGHIJ 2004-04-04 2001-01-01
6:  2   <NA>   <NA>       <NA> 2001-01-01
7:  3   KLMN   <NA> 2001-01-01 2005-05-05
8:  3   <NA>   <NA>       <NA> 2005-05-05
```

Desired output:

```
   ID  C_OPR  D_OPR       DATE  INDX_DATE ALFA
1:  1 ABCD01   <NA> 2007-07-07 2006-06-06    1
2:  1 ABCD11   <NA> 2005-05-05 2006-06-06    1
3:  1   <NA>  PQRST 2002-02-02 2006-06-06    1
4:  2   EFGH   <NA> 2002-02-02 2001-01-01    0
5:  2   <NA> EFGHIJ 2004-04-04 2001-01-01    0
6:  2   <NA>   <NA>       <NA> 2001-01-01    0
7:  3   KLMN   <NA> 2001-01-01 2005-05-05    0
8:  3   <NA>   <NA>       <NA> 2005-05-05    0
```

Logic:

Any `C_OPR` or `D_OPR` containing `ALFA_DEF` where `DATE` is less than `INDX_DATE` - in same group (`ID`), generates `ALFA` = 1, else 0.

Attempt without DATE correction:

```
DT[, ALPHA := +any( grepl(paste0(ALPHA_DEF, collapse="|"),c(D_OPR, C_OPR)), by=ID]
```

Preferably data.table solution but dplyr also welcome.

/H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do it this way:

After creating a new column `ALFA`
we check if
a) any `C_OPR` or `D_OPR` contains `ALFA_DEF`
b) `DATE` < `INDX_DATE`
then `ALFA` will be `1`
else `ALFA` will be `0`

```
DT[, ALFA := ifelse(any(grepl(paste0(ALFA_DEF, collapse = "|"), c(D_OPR, C_OPR)) & as.Date(DATE) < as.Date(INDX_DATE)), 1, 0), by = ID]
```

Output:

```
   ID  C_OPR  D_OPR       DATE  INDX_DATE ALFA
1:  1 ABCD01   <NA> 2007-07-07 2006-06-06    1
2:  1 ABCD11   <NA> 2005-05-05 2006-06-06    1
3:  1   <NA>  PQRST 2002-02-02 2006-06-06    1
4:  2   EFGH   <NA> 2002-02-02 2001-01-01    0
5:  2   <NA> EFGHIJ 2004-04-04 2001-01-01    0
6:  2   <NA>   <NA>       <NA> 2001-01-01    0
7:  3   KLMN   <NA> 2001-01-01 2005-05-05    0
8:  3   <NA>   <NA>       <NA> 2005-05-05    0
```

Answer (score 3):

We may do this as

```
library(data.table)
pat <- paste(ALFA_DEF, collapse = "|")
DT[, ALFA := +(any(Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, \(x) 
 grepl(pat, x[DATE < INDX_DATE]))))), by = ID, .SDcols = patterns("_OPR$")]
```

-output

```
> DT
   ID  C_OPR  D_OPR       DATE  INDX_DATE ALFA
1:  1 ABCD01   <NA> 2007-07-07 2006-06-06    1
2:  1 ABCD11   <NA> 2005-05-05 2006-06-06    1
3:  1   <NA>  PQRST 2002-02-02 2006-06-06    1
4:  2   EFGH   <NA> 2002-02-02 2001-01-01    0
5:  2   <NA> EFGHIJ 2004-04-04 2001-01-01    0
6:  2   <NA>   <NA>       <NA> 2001-01-01    0
7:  3   KLMN   <NA> 2001-01-01 2005-05-05    0
8:  3   <NA>   <NA>       <NA> 2005-05-05    0
```